# Show a print view of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to have a page where users can see the printable view of the web page. So that they can see how the page will look like in the print window, and if it looks good, they click a print button, and then the print window will be opened. ( So we can think that we have two buttons in the page, "Print the webpage", "Show as a print view" )

Could anyone let me know how I can show a page as if they are in print window please?

Answer (score 0):

Every user on your website can use the Ctrl/Cmd + P key to print your site out, or Ctrl/Cmd + S to save it, but you can use:

```
window.print()
```

function. It opens a dialog box, where the user can configure the print, and then allows them to print.

Comment: Yes, I can use `window.print()`, but is there a way to show printable view in a normal tab, not the print dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for. `var openingPreview = browser.tabs.printPreview()` will open print preview for the active tab. Check the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/printPreview

Answer (score 0):

MDN has what you're looking for ([See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/printPreview)) but it has a big limitation that it is supported only by the **Firefox** web browser, and thus there is no other choice than to use

```
window.print()
```

Unless you are going to use it only on firefox